# compute test metric on all folds of gridsearch

Tags: scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I am tuning a pipeline that includes imputation, standardization and prediction. It is implemented as an `sklearn` `Pipeline` and I am running `GridSearchCV` with k folds.
Is it possible to have the test metric be computed on the predictions of all folds concatenated rather than computing it within each fold and computing the average? How can I implement this?

Comment: This has been brought up before esp. wrt leave-one-out CV, but I'm not sure whether I've seen a reasonable solution.

Comment: @BenReiniger can you point out some links with possible solutions?

Comment: I wasn't able to find any when I first commented, and still can't.  You can dump the predictions out to a file or a global variable inside the scorer; https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/17083 has such code (although it also does quite a lot of other stuff).  The question is brought up in https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/15900 and https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/16353, but no real solutions there.

Comment: Another solution is to make the prediction your "score" for the fold.  Then `cv_results_` will already contain all the predictions.  You'll have to postprocess to find the best hyperparameter set and refit though.